# Cant get my text params to work with my query

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

My question is I have a auto populate method in my user controller that uses my visual model that compares whats typed in my view to what's in my employee table (Visual). For some reason I can't get it to find any values. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my user controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def populate_form
    @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])
    render :json => {

        :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name,

    end
  end
```

This is my visual model

```
class Visual < ActiveRecord::Base

  establish_connection :vmfg

  self.table_name = 'employee'

  belongs_to :user

end
```

This is my view

```
  <div class='row form-group'>
    <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
     <%= f.text_field :emp_id, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_id', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is what I get when it does the query

```
 Visual Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "EMPLOYEE".* FROM "EMPLOYEE"  WHERE "EMPLOYEE"."ID" IS NULL AND ROWNUM <= 1
```

But when I change my user controller to this it works my question is how can I use what's typed into my `emp_id` text field to be used when calling my populate form method?

```
  def populate_form
    @visual = Visual.find_by_id('BILL')

  Visual Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "EMPLOYEE".* FROM "EMPLOYEE"  WHERE "EMPLOYEE"."ID" = 'BILL' AND ROWNUM <= 1
```

Also for extra info this is my app.js that does the populate_form

```
$('#emp_id').change(function() {
      var url = '/user/populate_form/';
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        if(!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
        $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript function, you are not passing any parameters, you are just calling the method inside the controller. Try something like this:

```
$('#emp_id').change(function() {
  var url = "/user/populate_form&emp_id="+$(this).val();
```

Now the controller receives `emp_id` as a parameter.

Comment: That worked I'm getting the emp_id val to show up.. But now im getting this error tarted GET "/user/populate_form&emp_id=BILL" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-23 16:11:45 -0400 @MurifoX

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for UserController):

Comment: this is my route   resources :user do
    collection doe
      get :populate_form
    end
  end

Comment: @user3910236 Try `users/populate_form` instead.

Comment: In my route? or js? @MurifoX

Comment: I tried that and got this now Started GET "/users/populate_form&emp_id=BILL" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-23 16:58:19 -0400
@MurifoX
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/populate_form&emp_id=BILL"):